# Is money lending business wrong as per scriptures?

Tags: puranas, dharma-shastras, smriti

I heard many saying that those who earns money from this business will never be happy, etc etc. Also, kathakaars also say that sometimes. I am curious if it's mentioned in scriptures or anything regarding it.

Comment: See this -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16278/4732

Comment: @Rickross thanks, i got the answer.